# Link excel worksheets using perl

Tags: excel, perl, hyperlink

I am trying to write a perl script which links a cell value in say 1st worksheet to a value in 2nd worksheet using perl.
I tried using the following modules which were available in perl :-

1. Excel::Writer::XLSX
2. Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Can anyone help me with a simple perl script that does this.

Example :-

**Worksheet1**

[image]

---

**Worksheet2**

[image]

So, In the above example the Rules Column Items **R1**, **R2**, **R3** in Worksheet1 should be hyperlinks that takes us to Rules Column Items **R1**, **R2**, **R3** respectively when clicked.

Can someone show me how it can be done using perl or atleast push me into the right direction on how to use the module **Spreadsheet::WriteExcel** or **Excel::Writer::XLSX** for this problem.

Please help me out..!!

Comment: How do you even do that in Excel by clicking around?

Answer (score 4):

Using Excel::Writer::XLSX you would use the [write_url](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#write_url(_$row,_$col,_$url,_$format,_$label_)) followed by  [write_formula](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#write_formula(_$row,_$column,_$formula,_$format,_$value_)) method. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'test.xlsx' );
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet('Worksheet1');
my $worksheet2 = $workbook->add_worksheet('Worksheet2');

$worksheet2->write_string(0,0, 'Rules'); 
$worksheet2->write_string(1,0, 'R1');
$worksheet2->write_string(2,0, 'R2');
$worksheet2->write_string(3,0, 'R3');

my $format = $workbook->add_format( color => 'blue', underline => 1 );
$worksheet1->write_url( 1,1,  'internal:Worksheet2!A2', $format);
$worksheet1->write_formula( 1, 1, '=Worksheet2!A2' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Paddy Collins. I want to clarify a doubt here. As I see in the code that you have populated the columns using write_string method. But if I have say an array of these string how to use that to populate the columns ?

Comment: Vivek, read the instructions for Excel::Writer:XLSX. There is a lot of details in there. Do a for loop, or use write_col() or write_row().

http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm